# Making last integer disappear

Tags: c#, integer

I wanted to write simple program which will calculate the arithmetic sequence from a given formula (later I want to improve it by giving the formula on my own). I wanted the result in a given case not to exceed 15. The problem is that the program stops counting only after exceeding this 15 (in this case, when I insert 2 as a variable n, the penultimate number is 14 and the next 17 and only comes out of the loop). Can someone tell me how to do it so that the program 'forgets' this 17 and ends up with 14?

```cs
Console.WriteLine("The formula is 3 * n + 2");

Console.WriteLine("Specify n");
var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();

var x = 3 * n + 2;

while (true)
{
    if (x < 15)
    {
        x = 3 * n + 2;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        n++;
    }

    if (x > 15)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it only stops counting when it exceeds 15, try changing 'if (x > 15){ break;}' to 'if (x >= 15){ break;)'

Comment: "later I want to improve it by giving the formula on my own" Just a warning: Parsing Formulas from string inputs are a **very** advanced topic. Personally I avoid doing it, as it falls under "more trouble then it is likely to be worth".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of while(true) and break. But it is easily salvaged:

```cs
while (true)
{
    if (x < 15)
    {
        x = 3 * n + 2;
        n++;
    }

    if (x > 15)
        break;
    else
        Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Of coruse it might be better if you had a tail-controled loop like do...while, wich will output x at the start, do the calculation at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this is to preempt the calculation

```
while (3 * n + 2 <= 15)
{
   x = 3 * n + 2;
   Console.WriteLine(x);
   n++;
}
```

If you want a *DRY* solution so you don't have to re-specify the formula, you could take advantage of a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)

> Starting with C# 7.0, C# supports local functions. Local functions are
>   private methods of a type that are nested in another member. They can
>   only be called from their containing member.

```
// calculation is in one spot
int Calc() => 3 * n + 2;

while (Calc() <= 15)
{
   Console.WriteLine(Calc());
   n++;
}
```